# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Identity doesn't add any authentication data to my browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

The problem is that I used ASP.NET Core Identity to store user data, But when I logged in, it doesn't give any cookies or sessions to me. It just tells me that I've logged in successfully but next time I want to access the web page contains `[Authorize]` attribute, I just can't. It redirects me to the sign in page.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, true, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (ReturnUrl != null)
            {
                return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AppId))
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Authorize), new AuthorizeModel { AppId = model.AppId, RedirectUri = model.RedirectUri, State = model.State });
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok("You have successfully logged in");
            }
    ...... More code
```

`Startup.cs`

```
services.AddDbContext<PassportDbContext>(options =>
{            
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"));
});

services.AddIdentity<OAUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<PassportDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

-----------------------------------------------------

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
// app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

[Image: The cookies after I sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b44Ww.png)

That means the application doesn't give me any credentials that I'm signed in.

Comment: I think you should also provide the code related to auth in your *Configure* and *ConfigureServices* methods at startup.cs file. It looks like you havn't set the cookie auth schema properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net core 2.1 or higher on is built-in supports `GDPR` (General Data Protection Regulation).

and until you accept the cookie, cookie does not set in the browser.

add this following code to ignore `GDPR`

```cs
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ConsentCookie.IsEssential = true;
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```

```cs
 app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

Comment: @FarhadZamani From ASP.NET Core 3.0 + cookie consent is set to true by default because ASP.NET Core 3.0 + template removed the cookie consent needed alert partial view.

Comment: I do get SetCookie from the response HttpContext in the debugger. Does the cookie denied by the browser. I didn't use HTTPS

Comment: @Play_D This should not be an issue but you can check by enabling HTTPS.

Comment: @TanvirArjel `From ASP.NET Core 3.0 + cookie consent is set to true` Does that mean we can't change it?

Comment: I don't know. But it seems it has been fixed! I enabled SSL and used the code you give me. It works fine now!